# How to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac {n^{2}}{2^{n}}=0$ & $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac {n^{2}}{n!}=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponentiation, factorial

Prove that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac {n^{2}}{2^{n}}=0$$

I think I need to show $2^n \geq n^3$ $\forall n \geq10$. Is it true?

What about:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac {n^{2}}{n!}=0$$

What to do with $n!$?

Comment: Try L'hospital rule

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes :)

Comment: Alternative approach: Assume you have $2^n>c_kn^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$ and $c_k>0$ (for example $2^n>1\cdot n^1$). Then automatically (with $n=2m$ or $n=2m-1$ according to $n$'s parity) $2^n\ge\frac12(2^{m})^2>\frac12(c_km^k)^2\ge \frac12c_k^2m^{2k}>c_{2k}n^{2k}$ with $c_{2k}:=\frac18c_k^2$.

Comment: Think that $n!\ge 2^n$ !

Comment: [Here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489665/prove-that-if-k-in-mathbb-n-and-a1-then-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fra/) a more general result for the 1st one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fact:** If $a_n > 0 $ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big| = c < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Let $a_n = \frac{n^2}{2^n}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \Big|\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}{n^2}\Big| = \lim \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} < 1$$

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big| = c < 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

The second follows using the exact same idea.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital is too strong for this. Completely elementary, you can prove $2^n>n^3$ by induction: 
$2^n \times 2>n^3+3n^2+3n+1$ follows from $2^n>3n^2+3n+1$ which follows from $2^n>7n^2$ (for example). Using induction again, you can reduce this to $2^n>10n$ and then to $2^n>10$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use L'Hopital's rule. Recall that the derivative of $2^n$ is $\ln 2 (2^n)$:

$$y=2^n$$
$$\ln y=n\ln2$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\ln2.$$