# Prove that if $k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $a>1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^k}{a^n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that if $k \in \mathbb {N}$ and $a>1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^k}{a^n}=0$

I have this, I want to know if what I did is correct.

Let be  $a^n>1>0$, then:

$1>\frac{1}{a^n}$

Then:

$|\frac{1}{a^n}|<1$

Aplying archimedean property,for $ε>0$ exists $n \in \mathbb {N}$ such that:

$nε>n^{k+1}$

Then:

$ε>\frac{n^{k+1}}{n}=n^k$

Let be $ε>0$, exists $N=max(1,ε)$ that if $n>N$

$|\frac{n^k}{a^n}-0|=|\frac{n^k}{a^n}|$

$=\frac{n^k}{a^n}$

$<ε (1)= ε$

Therefore the sequences converges to zero.

Thank, you.

Comment: The archimedean property argument is incorrect, for example, let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, **not**: Your proof is not correct. Archimedean property does not imply that there exists $n$ such that $n \epsilon > n^{k + 1}$, since both sides depend on $n$. After all, this would imply $\epsilon > n^k \ge 1$, which is a contradiction whenever $\epsilon < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You must prove that for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>N$ it happens that $$\frac{n^k}{a^n}<\varepsilon$$
This is quite hard to prove directly. To prove that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^k}{a^n}=0$$
We can use L'Hopital rule $k$ times and find that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^k}{a^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{kn^{k-1}}{a^n(\log a) }=\ldots=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{k!}{a^n(\log a)^k}=0$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for a second the following is true $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n}=0 \tag{1}$$

Now, let's look at the original problem from a different perspective, e.g.
$$\ln{\left(\frac{n^k}{a^n}\right)}=\ln{\left(n^k\right)}-\ln{\left(a^n\right)}=k\ln{\left(n\right)}-n\ln{\left(a\right)}$$
$$k\ln{\left(n\right)}-n\ln{\left(a\right)}<-k\ln{\left(n\right)} \Leftrightarrow 2k\ln{\left(n\right)} < n\ln{\left(a\right)} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln{n}}{n}<\frac{\ln{a}}{2k} \tag{2}$$
given $(1)$ is true, $(2)$ is true as well from some $n$ onwards. But then, from some $n$ onwards we have
$$\ln{\left(\frac{n^k}{a^n}\right)} < -k\ln{\left(n\right)} \Leftrightarrow 0<\frac{n^k}{a^n} < \frac{1}{e^{k\ln{n}}}=\frac{1}{n^k}$$
and the result follows from the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

---

How do we prove $(1)$ though? Well, there are plenty of examples of this proof, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116392/prove-that-lnn-lt-sqrtn-for-n-in-mathbbn-without-derivative/2116532#2116532).