# If $n^k<2^n$, then $c\cdot n^k<2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following seems true, but I was wondering what the proof is.

I know that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n^k<2^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq N$. Is it true that there exists $N'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $c\cdot n^k<2^n$ for $n>N'$ for $c>0$.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: so to be clear: You have $c>0$ and want to find $N'\in\mathbb N$ such that $c\cdot n^k<2^n$ for all $n<N'$, correct?
By the way, what is $k$?
I assume it is a fixed positive integer.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I should have mentioned that, $k$ is a positive integer

Comment: This follows from $n^{-k} 2^n \to \infty$, or equivalently, $n^k 2^{-n} \to 0$.

Comment: Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489665/prove-that-if-k-in-mathbb-n-and-a1-then-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fra/) as a hint to answer your question.

Comment: So the statement is true?

Comment: Yes, I will add an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is correct:

It suffices to show this for natural numbers $k$ (since for a real number $r$ we have $n^{\lceil r\rceil}\geq n^r$.) Let $c$ be a fixed real number.

We have (by definition)
\begin{equation}
2^n = \exp(n \cdot \ln 2) := \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(n \ln 2)^m}{m!} > n^{k+1} \underbrace{\frac{(\ln 2)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}_{=:C>0}
\end{equation}
Thus $2^n > C\cdot n^{k+1} > c \cdot n^k$ for all $n > \dfrac c C$.