# Find the limit of the sequence $ \frac{x^n}{n^k}$ as $n \to \infty$ for all values of$ x > $0 and $k = 1, 2,\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, exponentiation, ratio

I have tried using the ratio lemma to tackle this question and also the fact $(n+1)^k \geq 1 + nk$ and I haven't reached an answer. How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Find $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ where $a_n=\frac{x^n}{n^k}$

Comment: limit is zero when $0<x\leq1$.And limit diverges to infinity when $x>1$.

Comment: And [one more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489665/prove-that-if-k-in-mathbb-n-and-a1-then-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fra/).

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$x\left (\frac{ n^{k}}{n+1^{k}} \right )= x\left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^{k}=x\left ( \frac{n+1}{n} \right )^{-k}= x\left ( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^{-k}$

Comment: oh I see! so tends to x?

Comment: correct that means an dosent convegre allways

Comment: what must be true to converge this limit think of that

Comment: surely this converges to x for all x>0? or does it have to be >1?

Comment: no this converge when an+1/an <1 , and you will have to check for an+1/an=1

Comment: Ah I see so if 0<=x<1 then converges to 0 and if x = 1 then an = 1/n^k so also converges to 0. For x>1 does the sequence just diverge then?

Comment: yes thats it. what year undergrad you are?