# For a fixed d, show that $n {{n-1} \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d} \leq o(1)$.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, approximation

> Given $p \in [0,1], pn^{(d+1)/d}  \to \infty$ and $np - \text{log}n - d \text{loglog}n \to \infty$, for a fixed d, show that $$n {{n-1} \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d} \leq o(1), \text{as } n \to \infty.$$

I’ve been stuck with this for a day. Taking log of the first expression for $p$ would give log$n$, but I can’t see where that loglog$n$ comes from.

Comment: Inequality you understand as "$\in$", correct?

Comment: Yes. The expression is actually the expected value of a random variable, and I want to show that it tends to $0$ as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

[From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\cdot \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we have
$$\color{blue}{n\cdot \binom{n-1}{d}\cdot p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}}=\\
(d+1)\cdot\frac{n}{d+1}\cdot \binom{n-1}{d}\cdot p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}=\\
\color{red}{\frac{d+1}{p}}\cdot\color{orange}{\binom{n}{d+1}\cdot p^{d+1}(1-p)^{n-(d+1)}}\tag{1}$$
Of course $p\ne0$, because $pn^{(d+1)/d}  \to \infty$ (otherwise it would $\to 0$).

Using [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$\color{orange}{\binom{n}{d+1}\cdot p^{d+1}(1-p)^{n-(d+1)}}\leq\\ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cdot p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\\
(p+1-p)^n=1\tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ altogether

$$\color{blue}{n {{n-1} \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}} \leq \color{red}{\frac{d+1}{p}}\tag{3}$$
The RHS is a constant, so
$$n {{n-1} \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}=\mathcal{O}(1)$$

---

**Update.** However, the question is about $\mathcal{0}(1)$. Let's note by $b=\max\{p,1-p\}\in(0,1)$. From $(1)$
$$\color{blue}{n\cdot \binom{n-1}{d}\cdot p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d}}\leq\\
\frac{d+1}{p}\cdot\binom{n}{d+1}\cdot b^{d+1}b^{n-(d+1)}=
\frac{d+1}{p}\cdot\binom{n}{d+1}\cdot b^{n}\leq \\
\frac{d+1}{p}\cdot n^{d+1}\cdot b^{n}=
\frac{d+1}{p}\cdot \frac{n^{d+1}}{\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{n}}=...$$
noting $a=\frac{1}{b}>1$
$$...=\frac{d+1}{p}\cdot \frac{n^{d+1}}{a^{n}}\to0, n\to\infty$$
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489665/prove-that-if-k-in-mathbb-n-and-a1-then-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fra/2489858#2489858) explains why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like the given assumption was not used?

Comment: Not directly. Indirectly, to conclude that $p\ne 0$. In any case $pn^{\frac{d+1}{d}}>pn \to\infty$ is obvious for $p>0$. And 
$$np - \log{n} - d \log\log{n}=
np-\log{\left(n\cdot\log^d{n}\right)}=\\
\log{\left(\frac{e^{pn}}{n\cdot\log^d{n}}\right)}>
\log{\frac{e^{pn}}{n^{d+1}}}\to\infty$$
too.

Answer (score 0):

Since $d$ is fixed, $0<p<1$ we can estimate
$$
n {{n-1} \choose d} p^d (1-p)^{n-1-d} \leq c\,n^{d+1}(1-p)^{n},
$$
which tends to zero, because $(1-p)^n$ exponentially small.
If I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: But how do you show $(1-p)^n$ tends to $0$ fast enough to cancel out the $n^{d+1}$?

Comment: @JoshNg Choose a positive integer $k$ such that $d+1\leq k$, and $1-p=\frac{1}{b}$, where $b>1$. So it is enough to prove that $\frac{n^k}{b^n}$ tends to zero.